# Where is my Organization Chart?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, user-accounts

All i am trying to achieve is to populate the "My Organization Chart", for new users it doesn't display anything:

[image]

For other users you are able to see the data: 
[image]

I tried to start the "start profile Synchronization" (full), which as far as I understand is supposed to pull the data from AD, but it just seems that SharePoint for all of the new users is not able to grab the data and display it. I read some documentation, but they all seem to point into creating a new profile which I am very skeptical in doing since i don't fully understand the ramifications.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You for reading.

Comment: Do the new profiles have a "Manager" property in AD? That's solely what the Organization Profiles work off of.

Comment: Have you ran a manual User Profile Sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the step by step:

1. Review the import logs, see if it is really getting all the data
   from the profiles (and check in AD if the user that has no Org Chart
   on his profile if he has a Manager or not, or if he has more/less
   data than the other users.)
2. If there is trouble importing information from AD, you account
   connecting to AD might not have access to read all values or
   accounts when running the profile import.
3. You can create a new user profile service to import information, usually users don't change their personal information on SharePoint so you should have no problem creating a new user profile service application.

Best of luck